# cause of Less::Error `unmatched '/*'`/ Sass::SyntaxError in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, semantic-ui, sprockets, fomantic-ui

I just switched from Semantic UI to the community maintained Fomantic UI in my Rails app, and get one of two obscure errors when using either the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fomantic-ui) or the [sass rails gem](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI-SASS).

1. With the npm package, I get `Less::Error unmatched '/*'` whenever the `stylesheet_link_tags` and such start to load fomantic assets in the document head. The fomantic styles and js are pulled into my project through the following two files:

   **application.css.scss**

   `*= require 'semantic-ui/src/semantic`

   **application.js**

   `//= require semantic-ui/dist/semantic`

   I notice that it works when I make both stylesheet and js load from `semantic-ui/dist`. However, doing that excludes a lot. Icons stop working. Relevant file stored in `semantic-ui/src` is **semantic.less**. Relevant files stored in `semantic-ui/dist` are **semantic.min.css** (which i do not require except for just now when switching things around to figure this out) and **semantic.min.js** (which i do require).

   Again, it "works" if I require the minified stylesheet in `semantic-ui/dist`, and it does not "work" if i require the **semantic.less** file in `semantic-ui/src`. Is this a problem with **semantic.less** or one of the other generated import files?
2. With the sass rails gem, I get a Sass::SyntaxError `Invalid CSS after "i.icon.stopwatch.": expected class name, was "20:before"`.

   Looking at the [source](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI-SASS/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/semantic-ui/elements/_icon.scss), I see a number of these declarations: `i.icon.stopwatch.20:before {content: "\f96f";}`.

   Why is *that* throwing an error?

Does this mean that the npm package and gem have invalid css or that my app is compiling incorrectly? I have no opinions about using the npm package or the gem, I just want it to work. Everything worked fine when I was using the old Semantic UI. I am extremely confused and would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With the npm package

It seems Sprockets doesn't support `less` from [README](https://github.com/rails/sprockets)

> Sprockets ... allows you to write assets in languages like CoffeeScript, Sass and SCSS.

So you can't use `/src` direcotry.

You could try to `import` `/dist`:

```js
# application.css.scss
import 'semantic-ui/dist/semantic'
```

2. With the sass rails gem

Thats a bug from [Fomantic-UI](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI/pull/1546)  already fixed, but have not been updated to [Fomantic-UI-SASS](https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI-SASS/issues/12)

Comment: yesss, i've been using the `/dist`, but it excludes some fonts and icons.

Comment: re `fomantic-ui-sass` - that gem and `fomantic-ui-css` are unusable. you can't override the styles in either :(

Comment: importing from `dist` is what I ended up doing at first. it works, but icons don't load. for now i'm pulling the script from a cdn and putting the `stylesheet_link_tag` after.

Comment: `import` from `dist` should work, it's hard to debug in this situation sometimes, so using `cdn` is not so bad.